# Space added at the end when rendered in HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I display name using value from model.

```
<div>
 @Modle.Name
</div>
```

Value is "Sam". But when i inspect this div in browser's developer tool, I could see some spaces added at the end as below.

```
<div>Sam     </div>
```

I tried below to remove those spaces but spaces are not removed.

> TrimEnd()
>   Substring

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps just inline it

```
<div>@Modle.Name</div>
```

The extra spaces probably wont make a difference though.